# Is there a way to use google Oauth api to check if the user has authorized the web app?

Tags: google-api, google-authentication

I'd like to show or hide a button that allows a user to log in via google based on whether or not they have created the account via google's authentication APIs.

I see that there was a "silent" (non-popup) way to check for authorization information with the `gapi.auth.authorize` by passing `immediate: true` when calling the function.  I don't see anything similar in the `gapi.auth2` library.

Is there a way to do this so that I can hide the log in via google button if they haven't authorized google to authenticate with my app using `gapi.auth2` or should I use `gapi.auth.authorize` to do it?